# how to prevent typescript type narrowing on assigned variables?

Tags: typescript

in the example below, i want to assign a variable like i do to `x1` and have it be type `C`. i can accomplish this with the way i do `x2` or presumably with `as` but that's clunky or unsafe. is there a nice way to do this? i'd like type `C` so that some type inference stuff later down the line works right.

```
type A = {foo: "foo"}
type B = {bar: "bar"}

type C = A | B

let x1: C = {foo: "foo"}
console.log(x1) // <- x1 is type A (what i want is for it to be C)

let x2: C = ((): C => ({foo: "foo"}))()
console.log(x2) // <- x2 is type C (desired)
```

[ts playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAzA9mgXFAROtOAvgLABQokUAQgsgEYCGATtjo00WWRdAMK1wAPtS6kANhGBQAHgEZs-RKgyt8nUgGM0AOwDOaCQDoxaAOYAKOQEooAeltQAPAFoZsqAEtdUHrCjmAdwALBikPKACGbTDvdCZPKWA0KDo+K1EJKWkAJgVac3MrPPgAPn9lLFw1QisrQrItPQMIYzNLbJt7J1ccz29ffnMAEwhdDyYIIasgA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it may be a case for a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) using `as`:

```
let x1: C = {foo: 'foo'} as C;
```

Though I'm not sure what use case might require TypeScript to not know what specific type of `C` value you've assigned to `x1`?

With the way you have it currently, TypeScript does know that `x1` is of type `C`. You can see this by trying to assign it a value of type `B` later, for example, and it will still work, though in that case TypeScript will still know you've given it a value of type `B`.

```
let x1: C = {foo: "foo", bar: 'bar'};
console.log(x1) // <- x1 is type A (what i want is for it to be C)

x1 = {bar: 'bar'};
console.log(x1) // <- TypeScript knows x1 now holds a value of type B
```

You can also see that if you assign it a type that matches `A & B` then TypeScript will not try to narrow its type any further than `C`:

```
let x1: C = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};
```

Comment: ah thanks! yeah i needed this because i was passing this value to a function that took in a generic. and i wanted “c” in that generic but passing it explicitly failed because it wanted a bunch of other generic arguments passed in… which i did not fee like figuring out. seems like a good case for “as” - which i normally avoid since it doesn’t seem very typesafe

Comment: Yeah I typically avoid (and recommend avoiding) using type assertions with `as` wherever possible for the same reason, but in a case this it's pretty safe.